# How to use url as locator in command Select Window

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, robotframework

Some of the links need to open in a new tab or new window of web browser. I was fail to select the new tab when I use url as locator in command `Select Window`.

**ENV:**

selenium2library,selenium2,robotframework,RIDE

**DOC:**

```
title   Select Window  title=My Document    Matches by window title
name    Select Window  name=${name}     Matches by window javascript name
url     Select Window  url=http://google.com    Matches by window's current URL
```

**Tried:**
It works fine with:

```
 Select Window title=mytitle
```

I was fail with:

```
 Select Window url=http://myurl.com/index
ValueError: Unable to locate window with URL
```

I didnt know how to get the name of the window, so I dind try to use name as the locator. But I want to use url, and I dont know how. Anyone has similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome webdriver 2.10 and Chrome 35. It seems that Chrome webdriver doesn't support 'Select Window' by url and I got the same error "Unable to locate window with URL". But select window by title works.

You can use javascript to get the title/name/url:

```
document.title
window.name
window.location.href
```

By the way, it seems that Chrome no longer listens to "Main" or "main" as the main browser window. So using 'Select Window' with zero argument in Chrome will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting value error because of using unknown title present in the browser. So before using "select window " you need to get length of window titles using command "get window titles" then its easy to check in your log file whether the value/title is present or not.

Follow the code format as follows in ride:

```
${Length}|Get window titles||||||
Select Window|       title of required page
```

Comment: question is about selecting window by URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the title that you can find by clicking on CTRL+U and copy it, you'll find it of course between the 'title' tags, example usinf firefox:

`Set Test Variable    ${link}    google.com
Open browser    ${link}    ff
Select Window    title=Google`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ${title_browser} =  Get Locations
Log  ${title_browser[1]}
Switch Window  url=${title_browser[1]}
```

i used above code and work